# Should I include impact factors / number of citations in publication list?

Tags: publications, citations, cv, impact-factor

I am writing a grant application for a post-doctoral fellowship, and I need to provide a publication list. In the list of papers published in peer-reviewed journals, I wonder if I should include the following information:

- Impact factors of the journal?
- Number of citations the paper actually raised?

One of the papers raised a pretty large number of citations (several hundreds) despite being published in a low IF, so I wonder how to carry this information...